# Count words with the letter 'w' in them but only the(almost done)

Tags: python

So the goal is to count the number of words in the sentence with the letter 'w', and I have written the code to count the number of w's but I can't get it to count the words in total.

```
items = ["whirring", "wow!", "calendar", "wry", "glass", "", "llama","tumultuous","owing"]
items = str(items)
acc_num = 0
for i in items:
    if i in ['w']:
        acc_num += 1
print(items)
```

Comment: Remove the `items = str(items)`.

Comment: output becomes 0

Comment: Okay, let me elaborate... after you've removed the `items = str(items)`, click the question I linked, read it, and apply the solution to your code.

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the letter w is in the word.

```
items = ["whirring", "wow!", "calendar", "wry", "glass", "", "llama","tumultuous","owing"]

count = 0
for i in items:
    if "w" in i:
        count +=1
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now